# Power BI Live Updates

Tags: azure, powerbi, appinsights

I'm using Azure App insights on my Xamarin app to track custom events.

I use the export option in Azure to export the data as an M query to Power BI - all works fine.

I've set up a report with some visuals and published as a dashboard.

I've set up a refresh schedule for the data in Power BI which is working but my report and dashboard visuals don't update to reflect the refresh of the data source and I was wondering what I am doing wrong?

Is there a better way to pull the data in? Ideally I would like close to live data from App Insights being pulled into a Power BI dashboard.

I've had a look online and some forums suggest that there isa refresh schedule option for the report but I can't find it and suspect it's dependant on the data source being used?

Thanks!